# Cant Connect The UIButton or UIImageView in Interface Builder

Tags: ios4, ios-simulator

i have 2 buttons and an image view that i am trying to connect in the interface builder. when i connect them to their respective IBoutlets the program crashes.

Answer (score 0):

crashes when you actually connect them or when you run the project?
im assuming you have the objects defined in you r .h file correct.
what is the output on the console? need more info!

Answer (score 0):

With assistant editor in Xcode, have the xib file and your .h file open in both windows, then control drag from your xib file the button and view to the .h file to connect them.